no view found for id 0xe2a for fragment screenstackFragment {fd62d7} (a33df46d-25b8-49e6-823c-829b8ba9b189 id=0xe2a)
i am getting this error while navigating between tab. I am using react native navigation for navigating between tabs but not fix this please help me fix this issue working on it for past 2 days but not able to fix it is it related to react native bottom tabs

use this code in your tab navigator
detachInactiveScreens={false}

your tab navigation should look like this
<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown:false}} detachInactiveScreens={false}>
<Tab.Screen
    name={STACK_NAMES.HOME_STACK}
    component={HomeStack}
    options={({ route }) => getTabOptions('Home', colorScheme)}
  />

</Tab.Navigator>
let me know if this solve your error
